# preg_match with 2 rules doesn't work

Tags: php, if-statement

I want that `preg_match` accepts `https://` and `http://` but also URLs without that like `google.de`, `sh.st` and stuff like that.

This if statement works, but it only accepts `https://` and `http://` URLs

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i", $flink)) {
    $html = "Error: invalid URL"; 
}
```

I tried this, but this doesn't work too...

```
$bd = "/^[a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i";
$dbb = "/^[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i";
if(!preg_match($bd, $flink)  || !preg_match($dbb, $flink))  {
    $html = "Error: invalid URL"; 
}
```

What is wrong? The problem page is https://viid.su

Comment: Do you realize the match for `$dbb` is commented out? Also the domain of a URL does not need to contain a `.` for local domains, ie: `http://localhost/index.php`. You might also want to be able to parse those.

Comment: no, also I know that it is commented out, just cause it didn't work

Comment: what about this ? `(?:https?\:\/\/)?`

Comment: Kazz instead of what ?

Comment: do you understand regular expression in your code ?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gU3ct9/3

Comment: how should the if statement look like ?!

Comment: it doesn't work for me

Comment: `if(!preg_match('/^(?:https?\:\/\/)?[a-z0-9\-_]+\.[a-z0-9\-_\.\/%&=\?\+]+$/i', $flink)){ $html = "Error: invalid URL"; }`

Comment: now it works :) ty

Comment: I just used the code generator on the regex page :))

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/
                ^-- removed a \ here.
```

for the second regexp. Then it will match `google.de` and `sh.st`.